# How to execute console commands in browser with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Is there a way to execute console commands in browser with selenium? (The browser type is of no importance.)

Here is an example:

[image: console in firefox]

Answer (score 3):

Executing commands in the Chrome console for the most part is simply executing javascript code.

Here is a sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = 'Path to ChromeDriver executable'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
#navigate to the url
driver.get("https://google.com")
#execute console command
driver.execute_script("date1 = '13-11-2015T17:25'; date2 = '25-11-2015T11:01';")
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result]